# maven-release-plugin does not include shaded artifacts

Tags: maven, lifecycle, maven-release-plugin, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to release a multi module project with shaded artifacts.
When I run the release:prepare then release:perform the artifacts uploaded to the Nexus repository include only the original jar and not the shaded one.

Is it possible that the Maven "release" runs before the "package" lifecycle?

The command I'm running is:

```
mvn release:prepare --batch-mode -Dtag=myproject-1.2.0.0000 -DreleaseVersion=1.2.0 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.2.0 -DremoteTagging=false -DsuppressCommitBeforeTag=true -Dresume=false
```

my parent pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>myproject</name>
<groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>myproject</description>

<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>distribution</module>
</modules>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- self-dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>development</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

The pom.xml of the distribution project looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
        my-project-parent
        org.my.project
        1.2.0-SNAPSHOT
    
    4.0.0

```
<artifactId>distribution</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
                <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>                
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>shade</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/myproject-${project.version}.jar</outputFile>
                                <createSourcesJar>true</createSourcesJar>
                                <filters>
                                    <filter>
                                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>log4j.xml</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </filter>
                                </filters>
                                <artifactSet>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>org.my.project:module*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </artifactSet>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

The folder on my computer has the shaded artifact, but the artifacts in Nexus repository conatin only the original empty Jar.

Is there a way to force the release to grab the shaded jar?

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to add the tag `<shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>` in your maven-shade-plugin configuration.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, 

Thanks! This solved my problem.

However, I'm using the tag <outputFile> to change the name of the shaded artifact. This tag overrides <shadedArtifactAttached>.

I moved the execution of the shade plugin to a project named the way I wanted the jar to be named, then I don't need the <outputFile> tag and used the <shadedArtifactAttached> one instead.